# ClassNotFoundException when deploy war to Tomcat on certain CentOS machine

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, centos, classnotfoundexception

I have a war file. It's Java 8 Maven application with some Spring, Hibernate.
I can successfully deploy it on my local machine (macOS).
Also I can successfully deploy it on VMware Fusion's virtual machine with CentOS 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 installed.
But I cannot deploy it on certain CentOS 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 server machine. I get the next ClassNotFoundException:

```
17-Feb-2017 18:21:54.727 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 31 more
```

In all three cases I just downloaded jdk1.8.0_121-b13 and Apache Tomcat 8.5.11 and indicated the JAVA_HOME for Tomcat (in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh) to point into folder where I placed JDK.

POM section with hibernate dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the latest version of all 3?

Comment: Have just tried with the latest Tomcat v9.0.0.M17 - the same result. Java v1.8.0_121 is already the latest version. I cannot change the version of CentOS (3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64) because it's hosting machine

Comment: Or you mean version of hibernate? I don't have the source code of the application (only war), but I will try to substitute the hibernate jars in {application}/WEB-INF/lib and will comment here about the result

Comment: I have changed the libs to hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar and hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.8.Final.jar (hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final is already latest version) and finally it worked. The war has successfully deployed into Tomcat v9.0.0.M17.

Comment: Yes I meant the jars. Glad to hear upgrading them worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Still don't know how it works without the latest libs on my local machine and on newly installed CentOS in virtual machine.